# How can I extract Signatures data from a Windows `exe` file under Linux using cli

Tags: windows, executable, signature

If you go to the [VirusTotal link](https://www.virustotal.com/nl/file/2bbb591d5aff30043923992d722d4611f383f2a3088cd7caca0955d27ec0bf96/analysis/#tab-item-detail) , there is a tab called file info(I think; mine is dutch). You'll see a header called

```
"Authenticode signature block and FileVersionInfo properties"
```

I want to extract the data under the header using Linux cli. Example:

> ```
> Signature verification Signed file, verified signature
> Signing date 7:43 AM 11/4/2014
> Signers
> [+] Microsoft Windows
> [+] Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011
> [+] Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010
> Counter signers
> [+] Microsoft Time-Stamp Service
> [+] Microsoft Time-Stamp PCA 2010
> [+] Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010
> ```

I used the `Camera.exe` in Windows 10, to somehow extract the data.

I extracted the `.exe` file, and found a `CERTIFICATE` file in it, there is a lot of unreadable data, but also some text, I can read, that is - roughly - the same like the above output.

How can I extract Signatures from a Windows `.exe` file under Linux using cli

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Linux there's a tool called [`osslsigncode`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/osslsigncode/) which can process Windows Authenticode signatures. Verifying a binary's signature produces output similar to what you show in your example; on a `vcredist_x86.exe` I have to hand I get:

```
$ osslsigncode verify vcredist_x86.exe
Current PE checksum   : 004136A1
Calculated PE checksum: 004136A1

Message digest algorithm  : SHA1
Current message digest    : 0A9F10FB285BA0064B5537023F8BC9E06E173801
Calculated message digest : 0A9F10FB285BA0064B5537023F8BC9E06E173801

Signature verification: ok

Number of signers: 1
        Signer #0:
                Subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation
                Issuer : /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA

Number of certificates: 7
        Cert #0:
                Subject: /OU=Copyright (c) 1997 Microsoft Corp./OU=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Root Authority
                Issuer : /OU=Copyright (c) 1997 Microsoft Corp./OU=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Root Authority
        Cert #1:
                Subject: /OU=Copyright (c) 1997 Microsoft Corp./OU=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Root Authority
                Issuer : /OU=Copyright (c) 1997 Microsoft Corp./OU=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Root Authority
        Cert #2:
                Subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA
                Issuer : /OU=Copyright (c) 1997 Microsoft Corp./OU=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Root Authority
        Cert #3:
                Subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation
                Issuer : /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA
        Cert #4:
                Subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/OU=nCipher DSE ESN:D8A9-CFCC-579C/CN=Microsoft Timestamping Service
                Issuer : /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Timestamping PCA
        Cert #5:
                Subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/OU=nCipher DSE ESN:10D8-5847-CBF8/CN=Microsoft Timestamping Service
                Issuer : /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Timestamping PCA
        Cert #6:
                Subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Timestamping PCA
                Issuer : /OU=Copyright (c) 1997 Microsoft Corp./OU=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Root Authority

Succeeded
```

You can also extract the signature:

```
osslsigncode extract-signature vcredist_x86.exe vcredist_x86.sig
```

Comment: Thanks, what about signature date? e.g. OP's example has `Signing date 7:43 AM 11/4/2014`.

Comment: This program is also available as a ["Homebrew" package](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/osslsigncode) for MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out https://github.com/msdhedhi/VerifyWinFileDigitalSignature

This is java code I wrote a while back which extracts and verifies the digital signature of a windows PE file( 32 bit and 64 bit )